# jQuery Ajax GET JSON array returns no results

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax

I am trying to make GET request and need to get the data from JSON with array and multiple objects.

If I try to do it with this JSON it does not working. (RETRIEVE FROM API)

```
{"Departments": [{"Dep_Code": "v1v", "Dep_Des": "dd1d"}, {"Dep_Code": "v2v", "Dep_Des": "dd2dd"}]}
```

I tried to remove the "Department" from the start, and changed the function like this:

```
$.each(departments.Departments, function (i, department)
```

to this

```
$.each(JSON.parse(departments), function (i, department)
```

And retrieve from the API this JSON, It works fine (without the object naming - one array) : (RETRIEVE FROM API)

```
{[{"Dep_Code": "v1v", "Dep_Des": "dd1d"}, {"Dep_Code": "v2v", "Dep_Des": "dd2dd"}]}
```

It works! But I need to do it with multiple objects.

On the each function there are no results. But if I `console.log(departments);`
, it prints the whole JSON but not able to iterate the results.

```
               // EXPLAIN:
         //this code is retrieved from the API a JSON I make. 
         //Append <OPTIONS> to existing <SELECT>.
         //The append not work, so just for the testing, 
         //I remark the Append function and just want to print the "Department", 
         //object from the JASON file
        var $departments = $('#department');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            url: "/api/SaveAttachments/GetDepartmentAndObject",
            success: function (departments) {
                console.log(departments);
                $.each(departments.Departments, function (i, department) {
                    console.log(departments.Departments[i]);
                    //$departments
                    //       .append($("<Option></Option>")
                    //           .attr(departments.Departments[i].Dep_Code, departments.Departments[i].Dep_Des)
                    //           .text(departments.Departments[i].Dep_Des));
                });

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            url: "/api/SaveAttachments/GetDepartmentAndObject",
            success: function (departments) {
                console.log(departments);
                $.each(departments.Departments, function (i, department) {
                    console.log(departments.Departments[i]);
                    //here department id is the select dropdown id and i created the dep_code as the attr and text as the dep_desc
                 $("#department").append("<Option "+departments.Departments[i].Dep_Code+"="+departments.Departments[i].Dep_Des+">"+departments.Departments[i].Dep_Des+"</Option>");
                });

            }
        });
```

Comment: Here, u directly given index size 0. Here u need to iterate entire json. Just increase the index accordingly.

Comment: Please format your code as well as put some description/help text for OP.

Comment: thank you for all comments. @RaviManiyar , I Just edited my question and code.